# Ubuntu 22.04 VPN issues (L2TP/IPSec)

Tags: 22.04, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I have a couple of machines running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I'm observing the same issue on all machines:

I can establish a connection to my VPN server.
I can ping machines, access internal websites, browse smb file shares, create ssh connection
But I cant:

Transfer a file via SMB or FTP (that I browsed before), sizes from a couple of KB till MB
Create a stream like with NoVNC (opened from a website that I can access)
I have crosschecked

different Ubuntu machines (clients)
different VPN accounts
different target machines
the same VPN connection (server and account) is working smoothly from iOS or Android.
Any idea what I can do to analyse the issue?

I have tried t already things like https://serverfault.com/questions/1090955/connection-failed-using-l2tp-on-ubuntu-20 without success.

Comment: Please check & correct your details; you've tagged the question as being about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but in the title mention 22.04.4 which is scheduled for release in January 2024 (*are you a time traveller?*) and also mention different versions of 22.04??  (all Ubuntu 22.04 releases will report themselves as 22.04; with the extra .2/.3 etc only showing upgrade level, so any .1 or .2 today just highlights owners not applying security upgrades!).